# Need help about $P\Gamma L_2(q)$, $q=4,3$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I am asking kindly,

> For which values of $n$ we have $$S_n≅P\Gamma L_2(3),S_n≅P\Gamma L_2(4)$$ This may be correct if we replace $S_n$ by $A_n$.

Any help will be appreciated. :)

---

Edit (JL): Adding the definition of the group. Let $\Omega$ denote the set $GF(q)\cup\{\infty\}$. Then the group $P\Gamma L_2(q)$ consists of bijections from $\Omega$ to itself the type
$$
P\Gamma L_2(q)=\{f:\Omega\rightarrow\Omega\mid f(z)=\frac{az^\sigma+b}{cz^\sigma+d}; a,b,c,d\in GF(q); ad-bc\neq0; \sigma\in Aut(GF(q))\}.
$$

This group has order $q(q^2-1)\cdot |Aut(GF(q))|$.

Comment: What does $P\Gamma L_2$ mean? Like, $PSL(\Bbb F_3^2)$? Every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of a symmetric group...

Comment: $P\Gamma L_2(q)=\{f|f:\Omega\longrightarrow\Omega, f(z)=\frac{az^\sigma+b}{cz^\sigma+d},ad-bc\neq 0; a,b,c,d\in GF(q)\}$, $\Omega=GF(q)\cup\{\infty\}$ and $\sigma\in Aut(GF(q))$. Yes exactly, but for some unknown values these groups $P\Gamma L_2(3)$ or $P\Gamma L_2(4)$ becomes isomorphic with some copy of $S_n$ or even $A_n$. I want to know these $n$.

Comment: Wait, isomorphic to a permutation group (subgroup of an $S_n$), or isomorphic to a symmetric or alternating group ($S_n$ or $A_n$ for some $n$)? These are radically different questions.

Comment: @anon: Maybe I wrote my answer incorrectly, but I want to find these $n$. I have no refrences noting for what value of $n$, the kenrel of the actions would be $\{\}$. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't understand the definition of the group! If you compose two such functions $f$, the power $\sigma^2$ emerges. IOW this set of transformations is not necessarily closed under composition??? Also, if you know the order of the group, then surely that determines $n$ uniquely. Of course, that doesn't mean that we would necessarily have an isomorphism with a symmetric (or alternating) group (that is surely the exception rather than the norm).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: $\sigma(z)=z^\sigma$ where in $z\in \Omaga$ and $\sigma \in Aut(GF(q))$. That takes time to show that this structure is a group of order $q(q^2-1)|Ant(GF(q))|$.

Comment: If that is the order, then your definition of the group is wrong. You should tell **inside** the parens that $\sigma$ can range over the Galois group. The way you wrote it gives the impression that $\sigma$ is **fixed**, in which case the "group" has an identity element only, if we picked $\sigma=id$.

Comment: Well, if that is the group order, then with $q=3$ we get a group of order $3\cdot 8\cdot1=24$, because the Galois group is trivial. Is this the order of a symmetric group $S_n$ or the alternating group $A_n$ for some $n$? Once you figure that out, then you know which isomorphism you need to prove.

Comment: It's a semidirect product $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\Bbb F_q)\rtimes \mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb F_q)$, where $A\sigma\cdot B\rho=A\sigma(B)\,(\sigma\circ\rho)$ and $$\sigma\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma(a)&\sigma(b)\\ \sigma(c)&\sigma(d)\end{pmatrix}.$$ @JyrkiLahtonen Babak *did* enclose $\sigma\in\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb F)$ in parentheses, however the last paranthesis was supposed to be a right curly bracket, and the definition was split into two lines.

Comment: @Babak, may be you have been unlucky to use a bit confusing English in the question. The way the question is written sounds like you are saying that the same group is isomorphic to $S_n$ for at least two different values of $n$. You obviously don't mean this. Are you simply asking for help in proving those isomorphisms?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Terribly sorry. I always mistype something here. I got the point. I forgot when an imbedded subgroup ( in $S_n$) has the same order of $S_n$ for some $n$, it would be the whole group as well. Thanks for saving me. :)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Yes you'r right. You hit the target. :)

Comment: @anon: Thanks for the time. Sorry for my bad English writting. Sorry.

Comment: Don't worry about bad English. You do fine. It really was unlucky that this time it was a bit confusing at first. Anyway, I added the definition of the group to the question body, because I think it belongs there. Feel free to edit it, if I did something wrong :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition $P\Gamma L_2(q)$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{Sym}(\Omega)\simeq S_{q+1}$. 
The claims would follow immediately from the knowledge of the order of the group $P\Gamma L_2(q)$:

When $q=3$, the group $Aut(GF(3))$ is trivial, and we have $|P\Gamma L_2(3)|=24=|S_4|$, so it follows that $P\Gamma L_2(q)$ must be all of $S_4$.

When $q=4$, the group $Aut(GF(4))$ is cyclic of order tow, and we have 
$$|P\Gamma L_2(4)|=4\cdot(4^2-1)\cdot2=120=|S_5|.$$ Again we see that $P\Gamma L_2(4)$ must be all of $S_5$.

So the real question is to prove the formula for the order of the group in these two cases.

In the case $q=3$ we observe that the transformations $z\mapsto z+1$ and $z\mapsto 2z$
give the permutations $\alpha=(012)(\infty)$ and $\beta=(12)(0)(\infty)$ of $\Omega$ respectively.
Clearly these two generate the group $S_3$ acting on the affine part $GF(3)$.
The transformation $z\mapsto 1/z$ gives the permutation $\gamma=(0\infty)(1)(2)$. Together with $\alpha$ we get a group that acts transitively on $\Omega$, because $\gamma(\infty)=0$,
and $(\alpha^i\gamma)(\infty)=i$ for $i=1,2$. Therefore the group generated by all of
$\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ must have at least $4\cdot|\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle|=4\cdot6=24$
elements, and hence be all of $S_4$.

For the case $q=4$ I write $GF(4)=\{0,1,a,b=a+1=a^2\}$. Here $F:x\mapsto x^2$ is the
only non-trivial automorphism. It corresponds to the permutation $\phi=(0)(1)(ab)(\infty)$.
In addition to that we have $z\mapsto z+1$ giving us $\alpha=(01)(ab)(\infty)$, and
$z\mapsto az$ giving us the permutation $\beta=(0)(1ab)(\infty)$. The elements $\phi$ and $\beta$
fix both $0$ and $\infty$, and we see that they generate a copy of $S_3$ acting on $\{1,a,b\}$. The group of translations $K$ generated by $\alpha$ and $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$, the latter
corresponding to $z\mapsto z+a$, gives us a copy of the Klein four group acting transitively on the finite part $GF(4)$. As in the preceding case we thus see that the group
$H=\langle \alpha,\beta,\phi\rangle$ generated by these three transformations must act as $S_4$ on $GF(4)=\Omega\setminus\{\infty\}$ because it has at least $4\cdot6=24$ elements.
It remains to show that adding the generator $\gamma=(0\infty)(1)(ab)$ gives us a group of size at least $120$. This follows from transitivity as in the case $q=3$. We can map $\infty$ to $0$ with $\gamma$, so $\gamma$ followed by an appropriate element of $K$
maps $\infty$ to any other element of $\Omega$. Therefore the order of the group
$G=P\Gamma L_2(4)$ is at least $5\cdot|H|=120$. As $G$ was known to be a subgroup of $S_5$, the isomorphism $G\simeq S_5$ follows.

Comment: Thanks for helping me step by step. By the way, we need a new tag here, "Linear Groups". I cannot make it but if think it is necessary to have this new tag, please make it for MSE. :-)

Comment: @Babak: Hmm. I'm undecided about the need of a new tag. I would use one of *algebraic-groups*, *lie-groups* or *finite-groups* all depending. It may be that there would be a benefit of singling out finite linear groups, so I'm not saying "No", either. I have never created a new tag, so I'm cautious. You can ask about this in meta.