# What are $P\Gamma L(n,q)$ and $P\Sigma L(n,q)$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I keep encountering the notations $P\Gamma L(n,q)$ and $P\Sigma L(n,q)$ in articles on group theory. I have more or less not been able to find references defining these groups, although [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165208/need-help-about-p-gamma-l-2q-q-4-3) defines $P\Gamma L(2,q)$; it appears to be more or less $PGL(2,q)\rtimes \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_q/\mathbb{F}_p)$. Do we have $\Gamma L(n,q) = GL(n,q)\rtimes\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_q/\mathbb{F}_p)$ and analogously for $\Sigma L$ and $SL$, and the $P$ is the quotient by the center as usual?

Comment: Don't those papers explain the symbol or at least provide references?

Comment: @Joanpemo: I don't think so. My impression is that these are relatively standard to finite group theorists and so they get used without comment in their papers.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

${\rm P \Sigma L}(n,q) = {\rm PSL}(n,q) \rtimes {\rm Gal}({\mathbb F}_q/{\mathbb F}_p)$.

The answer to your final question is yes, but you quotient by the centre of ${\rm GL}(n,q)$ (i.e. the scalar matrices) and not by that of ${\rm \Gamma L}(n,q)$, which might be smaller.